# reading Stripe webhook values in Json

Tags: php, stripe-payments, webhooks

I try to read values of a Stripe webhook in PHP.
Sent webhook has the following format:

```
{
  "created": 1312403445,
  "livemode": false,
  "id": "evt_00000000000000",
  "type": "checkout.session.completed",
  "object": "event",
  "request": null,
  "pending_webhooks": 1,
  "api_version": "2019-03-14",
  "data": {
    "object": {
      "id": "cs_00000000000000",
      "object": "checkout.session",
      "billing_address_collection": null,
      "cancel_url": "https://example.com/cancel",
      "client_reference_id": null,
      "customer": null,
      "customer_email": null,
      "display_items": [
        {
          "amount": 1500,
          "currency": "usd",
          "custom": {
            "description": "Comfortable cotton t-shirt",
            "images": null,
            "name": "T-shirt"
          },
          "quantity": 2,
          "type": "custom"
        }
      ],
      "livemode": false,
      "locale": null,
      "payment_intent": "pi_00000000000000",
      "payment_method_types": [
        "card"
      ],
      "subscription": null,
      "success_url": "https://example.com/success"
    }
  }
}
```

I write sent value to a table in a database. PHP in my server is:

```
    require 'connectFile.php'; // connect my database
    require_once('vendor/autoload.php');
    require_once('vendor/stripe/stripe-php/init.php');

    $input = @file_get_contents('php://input');
    $event_json = json_decode($input);
    $value_id=$event_json->data->object->id;
    //value_created= $event_json->created;

    $sql = "INSERT INTO myTable VALUES ("test","."'".$value_id."'".")";
    $prepare = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $prepare ->execute();
    http_response_code(200); // PHP 5.4 or greater
```

The problem is that when I try to read data-> object->id it writes 0 in the database. But if I read value_created= $event_json->created instead it correctly read the value.

Do you know what is wrong and why it reads 0 ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you prepared wrong query. Try:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO myTable VALUES ('test',':prepared_id')";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':prepared_id', $value_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
```

Also its safer method, because building strings in query isn`t safe :D

Comment: maybe some wrong with your database, some relations, triggers on something like this? i dont have anything else in mind.